# shell script with multiple prompts and options

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm writing a script to automate the Linux kernel building process. In my script, I have prompts, some yes/no, others are specific actions. Here's my questions:
How to properly close out a function and move to the next option after that function has ran?
How to jump to a specified action and bypass prompts/actions in between?
Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Do you need to install the necessary compiling tools?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) sudo apt-get install tools; break;;
        No ) <Here I want to skip to the next step. I originally left it 
              blank and removed the "done" command (after esac command) 
              to do this, but if I choose yes, it skips to the end 
              (where the next "done" command is and ends the script>
    esac

<I had to flip the yes/no for the script to skip to the next prompt>
echo "Do you need to eidt your configuration?"
select ny in "No" "Yes"; do
    case $ny in
        No ) <what do I put here to skip to the next tag 
             (labeled compile for example purposes); break;;
        Yes ) 
    esac

echo "You have 3 options with how you can edit you config file."
select yn in "Gtk" "KDE" "Terminal"; do
    case $yn in
    Gtk ) make gconfig; break;;
    KDE ) make xconfig; break;; 
        Terminal ) make menuconfig; break;;
    esac
done
done
done        <I had to insert all these "done" to end the file, but 
                 the scripts doesn't work the way I want it to...>
echo "Are you ready to compile"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) make; break;;
        No ) exit;;
    esac
done
```

So basically the scripts runs in stages.
1. Do you need to install tools
   - If yes, install them and go to the next step
   - If no, go to the next step
2. Do you want to edit the config file
   - If yes, how;
          - opt1
          - opt2
          - opt3
        -Then, when you are finished, skip to the next step
   -If no, skip to the next step
3. Compile

Comment: You mean something like `make oldconfig`? Or perhaps `make menuconfig`?

Comment: use your first case statement as a model for the rest, and eliminate the processing of the no option. your script will then "fall thru" to the next case block, where the same idea will apply. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Erm...

```
echo "Do you need to eidt your configuration?"
select ny in "No" "Yes"; do
    case $ny in
        No ) break;;
        Yes ) 
          echo "You have 3 options with how you can edit you config file."
          select yn in "Gtk" "KDE" "Terminal"; do
              case $yn in
              Gtk ) make gconfig; break;;
              KDE ) make xconfig; break;; 
                  Terminal ) make menuconfig; break;;
              esac;
             ...
          break;;
    esac
```

Or better yet, put each part in a function and call them as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks guys. This was the best answer: use your first case statement as a model for the rest, and eliminate the processing of the no option. your script will then "fall thru" to the next case block, where the same idea will apply. Good luck. – shellter... It jogged my memory into remembering how to do what I wanted to do. Ill post my script later for others to see. Since I'm a new user I can't answer my own question for 8 hours...lol